# Securing Smooch Webhooks

Tags: rest, authentication, webhooks, whatsapp, smooch

I use `smooch whatsapp` integration and `smooch webhook` to create a bot in whatsapp.

I want to **authenticate** the posts that come from my webhook.

I saw in the documents that there is a variable in the headers: `x-api-key`, that should be used exactly for that:

[image: x-api-key]

I can not find any explanation of how this variable is used. I realized that it contained the **secret key** of the `webhook`. But what else?

How do I create from the *data/body* another signature to check if it's match to what sent in the header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used [Smooch webhooks](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#webhooks) before, but my reading of their docs leads me to believe the following:

- The `X-Api-Key` isn't the usual webhook signature used to sign the payload. It's actually just a simple secret returned in each webhook POST request for an event.
- The secret is automatically generated when you [create the webhook](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#manage-webhooks) and returned in the `secret` field.
- You can also get the secret using the [GET webhook](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#manage-webhooks) endpoint. Other methods also appear to return the secret.
- Save the secret somehow, then simply compare the `X-Api-Key` header value for the secret on each webhook event request to verify authenticity.
- You could rotate the secret by programmatically deleting and re-recreating the webhook whenever necessary.

Comment: ^Correct. The X-Api-Key header is shared secret, not a digital signature.